# How to get Facebook friends using app with FQL query and Prime31 Social Networking plugin?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, prime31

I want to fetch Facebook friends using the Graph API or an FQL query.
I am using the Prime31 Social Networking plugin for Android.

Does Prime31 support FQL queries?

Comment: Seems like a question that would be better asked at http://prime31.com/support/